# Create a folder and store the file in it

Tags: android

I am downloading files using firebase. The code below downloads the file but to the root directory. What i want is to create a folder in root directory and store the downloaded files in it.

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://fir-896a6.appspot.com");

                    StorageReference islandRef = storageRef.child(fileName);
                    File localFile = null;
                    try {
                        localFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    islandRef.getFile(localFile);
```

I have tried using

```
localFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Student Portal/", fileName);
                        localFile.mkdirs();
```

It makes the folder Student Portal however instead of downloading file and saving it in the folder, it creates the folder inside the Student Portal folder named fileName and throws error

```
    E/FileDownloadTask: Exception occurred during file download
                                                                                    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Student Portal/proposal-1.docx: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
                                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
                                                                                        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
                                                                                        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
                                                                                        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                                                        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
                                                                                        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87) 
                                                                                        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72) 
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
07-13 21:14:39.217 14894-15750/com.horngmail.invisible.firebase E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                                                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                                                                                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
07-13 21:14:39.217 14894-15750/com.horngmail.invisible.firebase E/StorageException: /storage/emulated/0/Student Portal/proposal-1.docx: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
                                                                                    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Student Portal/proposal-1.docx: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
                                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
                                                                                        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
                                                                                        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source)


                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)


                                  Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
                                                                                at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                                                at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                                                at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 localFile.mkdirs();
```

Change to

```
 localFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

And remove that directory with the fileName first.